# Как прочитать файл в кодировке UCS-2 Big/Little Endian на Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть файл, его нужно прочитать и, например, сделать из него список строк. Файл в формате UCS-2 Big/Little Endian. Как его правильно открыть с помощью модуля codecs?
Версия Python 3.7.0. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Точно UCS-2, а не UTF-16?

Comment: @andreymal в gsm ещё используется

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[UCS-2 это предшественник UTF-16](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16), поэтому все символы UCS-2 являются подмножеством UTF-16.

> **U+0000 to U+D7FF and U+E000 to U+FFFF**
>
> Both UTF-16 and UCS-2 encode code points in this range as single 16-bit code units that are numerically equal to the corresponding code points. These code points in the Basic Multilingual Plane (BMP) are the only code points that can be represented in UCS-2.

Используйте `encoding='utf16'`.

Если в файле нет BOM ([Byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) - 2 байта вначале, определяющих Big или Little Endian), то используйте `encoding='utf_16_be'` или `encoding='utf_16_le'`, чтобы явно указать порядок байтов.

Вот ещё отличная статья на [Хабрахабр](https://habr.com/ru/post/377953/)

Comment: «поэтому все символы UCS-2» — прям даже из диапазона для суррогатных пар?

Comment: @andreymal, В Википедии и про них сказано - чуть пониже. А ещё я нашел отличную статью на хабре - поставлю линку в ответ

Comment: @strawdog, Посыпаю голову пеплом... Спасибо за правку!

Answer (score 2):

Для чтения SMS с модема (они в ucs2) достаточно кодека UTF-16.

```
import codecs
codecs.decode(ucstext, "hex").decode('utf-16be')
```

Простейший декодировщик выглядит так:

```
def decodeUcs2(byteIter, numBytes=256):
    """ Decodes UCS2-encoded text from the specified byte iterator, up to a maximum of numBytes """
    userData = []
    i = 0
    try:
        while i < numBytes:
            userData.append(chr((next(byteIter) << 8) | next(byteIter)))
            i += 2
    except StopIteration:
        # Not enough bytes in iterator to reach numBytes; return what we have
        pass
    return ''.join(userData)
```

Не помню откуда его взял, но вроде с англоязычного ресурса где дружат только с ASCII.